# Window 7 (64bit) Compatibility Issue with MikTex 2.9

Tags: miktex, windows, miktex2.9

I am trying to use MikTex 2.9 with Windows 7, but this is not supported: [image]

After a long search I found [this](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/setup/windows-x86?lang=en). Is this a right choice? I want to run TexStudio for writing articles.

Comment: there is no 86bit windows, you have either 32 or 64. And according to https://miktex.org/kb/prerequisites windows 7 is still supported so https://miktex.org/download should work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer see my updates.

Comment: Well do you know if you have 32 or 64 bit windows?

Comment: Here written System Type: 32 bit

Comment: Then you need basic-miktex-2.9.7269.exe and not the one with 64 at the end.

Comment: you mean in All downloads---->Basic Insataller 32bit @https://miktex.org/download